# Power of random signal in AM

Tags: power, communication, fourier, amplitude-modulation

I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem :

[image]

I must admit I'm pretty much blocked from the start, at a). I don't understand how I could derive the power of \$s_{AM}\$ given the frequency of the random signal is unknown.

I thought I could use autocorrelation to find the power of m(t) since it seems a random signal. The power of the 'b' component can be easily found as \$P_{b} = b^{2}/2\$.

For the message power, I'm just lost. Could Parseval be used? How can I find it not knowing the period of a 0/1? Help would be greatly appreciated. And if I was to find the average power of m(t), how would I find the average power of \$m(t)cos(\omega_c t)\$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: When calculating the average power the frequency doesn't matter. If the bit sequency(or waveform) is unaltered, the avg. power is unaltered too. Look at the common case of calculating the power of a continous sinewave. Would the frequency change the avg. power?

Comment: You're right. I was somewhat confused. I didn't notice given the fact the amplitude is either 1 or -1 (so |A|=1 is always true), the average power is A^2 for the square wave. And since it's multiplied by a cosine, the power of the modulated cosine will be A^2/2. Mea culpa for posting too soon.